# What's difference between these two code snippets?

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, select

```
public class RequestSell 
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string region { get; set; }
}

var model  = context.RequestSellctx
                    .Select(x => new RequestSellDto { ConsoleName = x.Name })
                    .ToList();
```

and

```
var model  =  context.RequestSellctx.Select(x => Map(x)).ToList();

private RequestSellDto Map(RequestSell x) =>
      new RequestSellDto {
           ConsoleName = x.Name
};
```

because when I execute, in T-SQL, the first example loads just specific columns of table, but the second code snippet loads all columns in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental difference lies in the expression in the `Select` method.

In the first case, you only use the `name` property, hence Entity Framework knows it can optimize the query for reading only that column. Note that from the `x` variable you only ever name the `name` property. Note here that the `RequestSell` is never really created.

The second snippet the variable is passed directly to a method for further processing. Entity Framework has no idea what the method will do, hence it assumes the worst and builds the full object, then calls the `Map` method and returns whatever it returns.

The important difference is that in one case the select expression is directly used and in other case it's passed to external code, effectively doing all the work client-side, while the first case delegates work to the server.